# Link-and-link-description-only answer

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

Am I right that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/119775):

> The [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) class, "[Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)", offers some great information for understanding and dealing with the exception `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: bitmap size exceeds VM budget when loading Bitmaps.

pretty much is an instance of this:

[image]

and can therefore be legitimately be flagged as ["not an answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/164088)?

Comment: It _is_ an answer. It may be minimal, but it does attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I would say so but as it is the accepted answer an NAA flag goes into the mod-queue and in there any possible outcome goes....  If the links would go to a paid/commercial training site we could flag it as spam but that wouldn't fly here.

Comment: @Cerbrus but if you leave out the links there is no new info other then already present in the question.

Comment: Good point, @rene. At very least, it's LQ, and by today's standards, should be deleted.

Comment: I left a comment on the question and answer to point out this question

Comment: @Cerbrus: You're right in the dictionary sense, but that's not sufficient on SO, which  has a narrower definition of what constitutes an answer. Link-only "answers" may attempt to answer the question, but on SO they still don't qualify as valid answers. The question I'm asking here is, is the example I give a minor variation on the link-only (non-)answer theme?

Comment: Imo, it is not. It _is_ an answer, but a low quality one. I've had plenty of _"Not an answer"_ flags declined on answers like this one.

Comment: It is clearly **not** an answer. It's a link and some text that says "This link solves $problem". There is **no** solution information *in* the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Without any context I would say you're correct in your assessment that the answer is an example of not an answer as explained in the epic post from [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) with the title [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

The answer uses a clever disguise (intentional or not) by using more words instead of the dead-obvious *look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289527/should-we-consider-an-answer-with-great-links-to-be-an-answer?rq=1)*. If you leave out the links the answer doesn't add anything new already known from the question.

There are a couple of problems however on how to handle this. First of all the answer is accepted by the OP and was not the first choice. The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/477572/timeline) shows three different accept events where the current highest voted answer was accepted before. Based on that you could assume the current accepted answer helped the OP most.

Glancing over the content in the links I see bits that are also in the other answer so I'm not comfortable editing the useful content from the links into the answer so it can stand on its own. So salvaging that answer in this way is only possible by the answerer.

As that answer got over 200 up votes, down voting it doesn't make much difference, especially because the whole question and all its answers are community wiki. No reputation will be harmed in that process.

You could leave a comment for the answerer to suggest editing in the relevant parts of the linked content.

Flagging the post as not an answer will send it to the queues but due to the fact that the answer is accepted it will also end-up in the moderator queue. It then depends on the subject matter expertise of the moderator if you're flag is handled as helpful. If you look at the first comment of @Cerberus on this question you'll realize that a moderator can decide in a similar fashion, causing the flag to be declined.

One option is to use the [other flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251145/when-is-further-explanation-a-custom-flag-required-for-not-an-answer) but that needs a very solid explanation because you need to convince a moderator to remove an accepted answer that in a sense is helpful and has high view rates. Maybe convert it to a comment.

The best option for the specific answer would be:

- leave a comment under the question and ask if the OP is sure about the accepted answer
- leave a comment under the accepted answer and ask to get the relevant parts edited in (or do it your self if you're a SME)
- Up vote the other answer(s)
- Flag other with a clear explanation why it should be deleted/converted to a comment (but don't  whine if it gets declined)
- Shake your head and move on

Comment: *"Shake your head and move on"* <- this. It would be interesting to know whether converting an answer to a comment preserves the score.

Comment: @ArtjomB. [Can we please clear misunderstanding that deleting old highly upvoted posts causes reputation loss?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290370/839601)

Answer (score -4):

I've declined NAA answer flags on the post on the basis that the whole post, including the answers, is CW. That means the community can fix this without moderator intervention.

Besides, the post has been found helpful by a lot of people, and moderators are always cautious with just removing such content outright.

*Just edit the posts*, the threshold for editing is lowered for a reason.

Comment: So if someone posts spam, but marks it CW, it shouldn't be flagged  or deleted because community members could edit it into a good answer?

Comment: The handling of the flags is inline with what I predicted, the *just edit the posts* is in general good advice but for the specific case not obvious as I tried to explain in my answer.

Comment: Also note that this post isn't actually a collaborate work of multiple users, nor is it intended to be such by its author.  It's CW purely because the question has so many answers they were auto-CW-ed.  If someone wants to just write an entire answer from scratch, they can just post their own answer, not completely re-write the accepted answer to the question that has *dozens* of other (much better) answers.

Comment: @Servy: yes, lets apply reductio ad absurdum to this. I was appealing to some common sense.

Comment: So you're saying that we should keep an answer that in no way answers the question because someone else could completely rewrite the entire answer, from scratch, keeping nothing of the original?  If someone wants to write an answer from scratch let them post their own answer, rather than editing their brand new post into an existing bad answer.

Comment: @Servy: adding in a summary is not a rewrite. You get the exact same result except the answer doesn't become worthless if the link went away.

Comment: If, after the edit, nothing of the current post would be left, I'd call that a re-write.

Comment: IMO, it could be ok to left a CW answer alive but... This answer offers nothing than a link to an official android developer lesson and it is the **accepted** answer.
Accepted answers should be the ones which offers a good solution to the problem, it might not offer the best solution within the answers but it should **offer** a solution. Users first check the accepted answer if there is any. And this CW answer is only offering a link not an answer.
Deletion of the answer will make good answers more visible since there would be no accepted answer.

Comment: @rene: What's wrong with editing the post to include the essential parts of the training resource, if you want to? Sure, some of the other answers provide a similar solution, but this is the official guide, and it is slightly more comprehensive (and neat) than any individual answer there. What's the point in deleting it when it is accepted and helping lots of people?

Comment: @Servy: At this point a new answer would never reach any visibility there unless it's also accepted. There is a practical aspect here that would not be present in newer questions containing fewer answers.

Comment: @FallenAngel: Perhaps it was accepted because it linked to the most useful/comprehensive solution? Blindly deleting answers that lots of people find useful based on indiscriminate application of a general policy, and without even attempting to fix/improve it, does not seem to be a sensible thing to do…

Comment: @corsair992 If a new answer wouldn't get visibility because there are too many fantastic answers above it, such that nobody is in need of any other information, I don't consider that a problem.  If it wouldn't add value, then it wouldn't add value.

Comment: @corsair992 Considering that there is an answer with a score that's *more than 450 higher than the answer in question* I think it's pretty safe to say that the answer *isn't* considered the most useful or comprehensive solution by the community.  One person's opinion isn't worth that much more than everyone else's.  Blindly clinging to a bad answer just because the person who asked the question liked it more than *hundreds more other people* doesn't mean that it's particularly valuable.

Comment: @Servy: If a new answer doesn't gain visibility because it replaced an existing highly voted and accepted answer, and was pushed to the second page beneath answers gaining votes for 6 years, then I _would_ consider it a problem. The extra votes on Fedor's answer are probably owing to the fact that it was posted 3 years previous to that answer, at a time when the official guidance didn't even exist, was accepted for about a year, and was useful for a lot of people during that interval. Doesn't mean you should be deleting new useful answers though (which is still ranked no lower than third).